# Cannot seed database; not working because of refused connection?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, sunspot

When I try to seed my application I get the error:

> No connection could be made because the - target machine actively refused it. - connect(2)

I believe the reason why is because I was having issues with mysql2 so I uninstalled it along with the MySQL 5.5 Servers and then switched to sqlite3. I think the server for mysql2 is running in the background so this could be the issue. How would I fix this? How would I turn off the Mysql2 local host server or whichever server it is that's causing this issue?

I am running on Windows 7 64-bit.

```
Rails 3.0.9
SQLite3 1.3.4
```

Thanks.

Note: I can migrate and drop fine.

Edit:

config/database.yml

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

UPDATE:

I tried restarting the PC and also remade my application from scratch, still get the error. Disabled Windows Firewall/Comodo Firewall and tried again, still failure. I did a System Restore but this did not work either.

Here's the full `rake db:seed`: https://gist.github.com/1375566

---

**SOLVED:**

I have another application I ran `rake db:seed` in and it worked correctly, so as the accepted answer by clyfe pointed out, Sunspot was the issue. I put together again my application and stopped at adding sunspot and suddenly I got the error:

```
rake db:seed
(in C:/testagain)
Deleting database now...
rake aborted!
undefined method `searchable' for #<Class:0x52cdca0>
```

Which means the rake was reading my code inside of my UserPrice model that dealt with Sunspot:

```
class UserPrice < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Sunspot and Websolr configuration.
  #searchable do
   # text :product_name do
   #   product.name
   # end
 # end
end
```

I commented this out and was able to seed correctly. Then I went on to try sunspot using these commands in the following order:

```
rails g sunspot_rails:install
rake sunspot:solr:start (also un-comment model)
rake sunspot:reindex
rails server
rake db:seed
```

Everything works as it should.

Comment: What does your database config file look like? I'd be surprised if there was a conflict between a dev sqlite3 and mysql.

Comment: @DaveNewton I put the file in my Edit: section.

Comment: rails will connect the database adapter in your database.yml ONLY.

Comment: @xxd OK, good information. What do you think I should do? How do I stop all connections?

Comment: I just had this problem also, thanks for figuring it out, but I almost kept searching. Just to be clear, the problem isn't "Sunspot", as you said. I think saying "it was sunspot" is a little misleading. For example, when I read that, I thought "well, Sunspot isn't even running, so it can't be the same as my problem". The real problem is that Sunspot was not running at the time you ran db:seed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using [Sunspot](http://outoftime.github.com/sunspot/) for indexing and search as I see from your gist https://gist.github.com/1375566
**Make sure that the Solr server is started before you seed.**

What happens is that:

- when the model saves
- it tries to send data to the Solr server for indexing
- **but** it cannot connect

Possible issues:

- the Solr server is not started
- the Sunspot Solr connection is not configured corectly in `/config/sunspot.yml`
- the port it's blocked by a firewall

If you haven't started a Solr server instance already, you can start the Sunspot-bundled Solr server with the following rake command:

```
rake sunspot:solr:start
```

Comment: Thanks, after some playing around was able to get everything working. It was sunspot after all.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think it is because of mysql, I think it is a firewall issue on the port that you are trying to access. You can test by stopping the service or using the mysql workbench to stop the server on that machine. I doubt that will resolve the issue, since the firewall may be interfering.

Comment: What service is this? And I am using Sqlite3, the MySQL Workbench has been deleted.

Comment: But you have Mysql installed or from a zipped directory?

Comment: I also got rid of the MySQL 5.5 Servers. Right now Sqlite3 is running from the sqlite.exe, if that's what you mean.

Comment: okay, my original point was mysql is not interfering it is more likely your firewall

Comment: Its interesting, I did see my Windows Firewall on, so I turned that off and also turned off Comodo. I ran rake db:seed again and still get the same error, maybe its a port issue? By the way I can connect on the rails server with no issue.

Answer (score 0):

Comment out the skip-networking in my.cnf in your MySQL configuration.

Comment: my.cnf? Where can I find this file? I don't see it in my Rails application.

Comment: @JustinRoR: no you don't have my.cnf, coz you are using sqlite.

Comment: @xxd Thanks for the clarification, I had no idea what he was talking about.